# Why do P/PI/PID Controllers exist when we can manually code in software (say an Arduino).

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, pid-controller

Just wanted to know why these separate controllers exist when it can be done in software itself say for instance, the Arduino. You can still tune the response by changing values in the code. 
Also, in a broader sense, why does the industry use PIC/ARM microcontrollers when there is an easy alternative (Arduino) which is easy to learn and doesn't need 2 or 3 interfacing devices to connect to the pc and upload the program.

Please answer this question in a two part format, for both the questions.

Comment: Why have volume and tone controls on a hifi when you could have a little hole that you inserted a screw driver to make adjustments? Why bother with learning to balance on a bicycle when you don't need to learn that if you use a tricycle?

Comment: Because you don't need a microcontroller to run a PID controller?

Comment: Mmmhh... Maybe the PIC/ARM industry was already there before Arduino even existed? Just saying. Oh, and maybe because there are tools that may suit some applications better than others? just saying, too.

Comment: If you already think you can split the answers in two parts, you should have asked two *separate* questions. I'm going to go ahead and remove the second question, to save your question (a bit, it's still horribly broad) from being closed as "too broad".

Comment: You're aware that some versions of Arduino are actually *made* out of ARM chips? So it is a bit like saying "why use an engine when you can use a car?". Maybe, sometimes, you don't need the steering wheel, brakes, seats, etc... Just the engine.

Comment: Why they still produce cars? In a junkyard you can find many pieces to DIY a car.

Comment: to top that off, if someone has to write microcontroller firmware that has to pass a code audit, like, for example, someone who's building a industrial controller, he'd be submitting all used arduino libraries along with his code for audit. I'd very strongly presume that the result of that audit will be ... interesting. Also, arduino sketches are really not the tool of choice if you're actually a bit into embedded development, imho.

Comment: I think you may be overestimating the amount of code auditing that goes on, Toyota passim.

Comment: @pjc50 ooouch. yes.

Comment: What's the 'please answer this question in a two part format' all about? Looks like a homework requirement.

Answer (score 12):

The question is really about the difference between a hack and a product.

An Arduino on its own is a caseless, non-shielded device that has no input/output protection. To modify its behaviour you modify the code. You can't buy one, put it in a factory, and expect it to carry on working.

An [industrial PID controller](http://www.process-auto.com/product/pid-controllers) on the other hand is a proper *product*. It has a case, fits a DIN rail system, interfaces with sensors and control devices from the same or other manufacturers, complies with safety standards, is protected against EMI and ESD, probably comes with a service guarantee and so on. It has a little screen and buttons so you can adjust it without having to reprogram it.

(The reason I've bothered writing this answer is that a lot of people don't appreciate the distinction and why it's so expensive to go from a bench prototype to something you can actually sell to customers.)

Answer (score 4):

Why do we have arduinos when the same thing can be done by getting a micro more target for the specific job and adding the circuitry around it yourself?  Why are there such things as TV dinners when you can get the ingredients and prepare them yourself exactly as you want?  Why are there ready to wear shirts when you can get the cloth and make one yourself?

Think about it.  The answer to all these questions is the same: Because sometimes convenience and having it done by someone with special expertise is worth it, in return for higher cost (sometimes not even that, see @pjc50's comment) and maybe not getting something that exactly fits the purpose.

This really should have been obvious.

Comment: These days mass-manufactured goods are nearly always *cheaper* than even buying the materials to DIY, let alone the time and effort in DIY.

Comment: @pjc50: True, for high volume products where the market forces low margins.  Arduino is a example where this is not the case.  You can put a microcontroller on a board for less.  Same with the TV dinner if just looking at material cost.  However, none of this is the point here, which is that there is a market for most things at various levels of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Analog computing has its advantages:

1. It is robust - no software bugs to worry about.
2. It is intuitive.
3. It is fast - calculation is done real time, short of delays in the circuit.
4. It can be done inexpensively.
5. It can be done without those high tech mumbo jumbo.

....

All make them suitable for certainly applications.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino is a "platform": a combination of hardware, software, libraries and examples that make development for beginners easy.

It's also (in the ATMEGA328 format) rather expensive, hilariously large, not particularly good for power consumption, the "shield" interface is badly laid-out on the PCB, and only has a particular set of peripherals. Ease of development is not the only consideration!

(Edit: bah, Marcus has deleted the second question to which this was a reply!)

Comment: Oh sorry, Think I should roll that back then?

Comment: Leave it a bit and we'll see where this ends up; if OP posts it as a separate question I'll move my answer there.

Comment: problem is that I'll have to leave for now; so please just assume my agreement with whatever you do to my edit :)

Comment: Roll it back is my vote.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I won't be posting a seperate question, I already have my answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do P/PI/PID Controllers exist when we can manually code in
>   software (say an Arduino).

Because sometime speed, size, cost, accuracy, reliability or power consumption matter.

> Why does the industry use PIC/ARM microcontrollers when there is an
>   easy alternative (Arduino)

Why do people use faster, lower power more capable processors when a slower alternative with a hacked almost but not-quite c programming interface is available?

Maybe because they need more than one serial port that runs faster than 9600 baud. Yeah, that must be it, I can't think of any other reasons.

<sub><sub>Do I need sarcasm tags there or is it obvious enough?</sub></sub>